# How do I vertically center a pseudo element image in CSS?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

There are a couple similar questions I've found out there, but none of the answers have worked. Here's my issue:

I'm trying to insert and center a decorative bracket image before and after some content like this:

[image]

Since I have two images, I can't insert them using a background property (in CSS2). So I'm using the :before and :after tags like so:

```
p#special:before { 
    content: " "url(/images/left-bracket.png);
}
p#special:after { 
    content: " "url(/images/right-bracket.png);
}
```

Unfortunately, this ends up aligning the images to the baseline of the text like this:

[image]

I've tried applying "vertical-align: middle" and "vertical-align: -50%" to the pseudo elements with no success. They move slightly, but not to the middle as demonstrated above.

I've also tried applying vertical-align to the paragraph itself with no success.

I've tried adjusting the height of the paragraph to the height of the image in combination with various vertical-align values.

I've also tried adjusting the line-height of both the paragraph itself, and the pseudo elements. This didn't work either.

I can position the brackets exactly where I want them using something like "position: relative; top: XXpx;" on the pseudo elements, but if I have more than one line of text, or a different font size in some cases, the brackets will no longer be centered. I want the images to always be vertically aligned to the middle of the text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
p#special{
    position: relative;
}
p#special:before { 
    content: " "url(/images/left-bracket.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
}
p#special:after { 
    content: " "url(/images/right-bracket.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ansyori. I tried this, but for some reason, it aligns the top of the image (as opposed to the middle of the image) to the 50% mark of the content. I could adjust the images up to where I want them using top: 0, but then they won't be in the middle if the content height changes. thanks for the help though!

Comment: I realize I can use your solution in combination with a negative top margin on the pseudo elements (equal to half the size of the images) to ensure that the images are always centered. Not a very pretty solution, but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
p#special:before { 
    content: " "url(/images/left-bracket.png);
    margin-top: 5px /*Offset margin, adjust accordingly*/
}
p#special:after { 
    content: " "url(/images/right-bracket.png);
    margin-top: 5px /*Offset margin, adjust accordingly*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks jack. I considered just using a hard coded margin-top, but as mentioned, I needed the pseudo images to remain centered if the height of the content happened to change. I ended up using a modified version of Ansyori's solution. Thanks!

Comment: Your most welcome, I'm happy that you've found a solution. Good luck with your site.